# Change opacity of part of an image on hover

Tags: css, hover, opacity

How do I change the opacity of the button only upon mouse hover.

```
<style>
.change_opacity:hover{

/* FIRST (order is important) */
opacity: 0.7;

/* SECOND (IE8) */
-ms-filter:”progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)”;

/* THIRD (IE7) */
filter: alpha(opacity=70);
} 
</style>

<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xiwLYMExzi8">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/nGiyduv.jpg" alt="potatos" class="change_opacity"></a>
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/nGiyduv.jpg button's in the image

Comment: You will have to use an image map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an 'image map'. It is a way of breaking up different parts of an image and being able to do different functions with them. I have created image maps before to have separate parts of the image go to different URLs.

There are a lot of online tools available to assist you in making an image map. You may be able to play around with some settings [here](http://www.image-maps.com/) to adjust CSS properties

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a CSS class it would be like:

```
.whateverClass{
  opacity:0.5;
}
.whateverClass:hover{
  opacity:1;
}
```

Change the `whateverClass` to your class, and adjust the opacity accordingly.

Comment: i only want to change the opacity of the small button inside the picture, not the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that as is. AFAIK, it's not possible to select part of an image to affect with css; the browser can't tell that part of that image is a button! Cut out the button and make it a separate div and then do what PHPglue said.

Comment: so i should cut out the button, overlay it on top of the blue background, and then use PHPglue's script?

Answer (score 0):

**change your code:**

```
 <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xiwLYMExzi8">
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nGiyduv.jpg" alt="potatos" class="change_opacity" >
 </a>
```

**TO:**

```
 <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xiwLYMExzi8" class="change_opacity" >
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nGiyduv.jpg" alt="potatos" />
 </a>
```

**and your css will be:**

```
.change_opacity{
   opacity: 1;
}

.change_opacity:hover{
   opacity: 0.7;
}
```